# How to get X and Y position of Image inside a ListView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, position

I need to show a `tooltip popup` when the images inside a `listview` is tapped. For that i'm creating a absolute layout page and adding the `listview` and the popup layout inside the absolute layout. I'm then trying to use the `Position of the Image inside a listview` to place the popup layout just below the image.

**But the image X position is returning some value but the Y value returns 0 always.**

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy NuGet package called MR.Gestures that provides (among other things) X- and Y- screen coordinates of a tap location.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm looking for a custom implementation, as i think using custom controls or implementation i can customize the way i want.

Answer (score 0):

We could achieve this by following the code in this link [Getting X and Y coordinates](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86941/get-x-y-co-ordinates-in-tap-gesture-inside-listview) but again its not giving the screens X & Y position.